# Ember DS.Errors troubleshooting on create form

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a basic create form setup which has validation on the name field. The save action for the form has a promise to gracefully hold the error:

```
    actions: {
        save: function(){

            var route = this;

            var createCampaign = this.store.createRecord("campaign", {

                code: this.get("code"),
                name: this.get("name"),
                description: this.get("description"),

            });

            this.set("code",""),
            this.set("name",""),
            this.set("description",""),

            // POST values to campaigns

            createCampaign.save().then(function(c){

                route.transitionToRoute("campaigns.view",c.id);

            }, function(errors){


            });
        }
    }

});
```

My defining attributes is:

```
    TM.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    code: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(),

});
```

I've read that by using a RESTAdapter, the `ajaxError` needs to be overwritten, so I've added the following:

```
ajaxError: function(jqXHR){

        var error = this._super(jqXHR);

        if(jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422){

            var response = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

            errors = {}

            if (response.errors){

                var jsonErrors = response.errors;

                Ember.keys(jsonErrors).forEach(function(key){
                    errors[Ember.String.camelize(key)] = jsonErrors[key]
                });

            }

            return new DS.InvalidError(errors)

        } else {

            return error

        }

    }
```

The response which is coming from the API is structured as:

```
    {

    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ]
    }

}
```

But for some reason, whenever I try to display DS.Errors (using `console.log(route.get("errors")`), I get undefined. It's like Ember doesn't know that a validation error has appeared within the response.

I've also made sure that the response status comes back as `422 Unprocessable Entity`. Can anyone see what I'm missing??

**EDIT:** I have been able to create a JS Bin to demonstrate my problem: http://jsbin.com/xujari/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your jsBin slightly modified :

http://jsbin.com/luwaqeyoca/1/edit?js,console,output

The description of [DS.InvalidError](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.InvalidError.html) never state about setting an error in the route. The sure part is that it sets the promise rejection error. It's also set an error property on the `record` it self if the property has a property maching the error key name (in breafe if your error key is `name` you HAVE TO have a property `name` in your model)

```
        createCampaign.save().then(function(c){
            route.transitionToRoute("campaigns.view",c.id);
        }, function(errors){
                console.log(errors.errors.name);  //from the promise error 
                console.log(createCampaign.get("errors.name")); //from your record

        });
```

**EDIT**

Here is a bin modified as you asked in comments
http://jsbin.com/sokebuzumu/1/edit?html,js,output

you need to create an empty object "errors" in your controller as in the jsbin

```
  createCampaign.save().then(function(c){

        }, function(errors){
            this.set("errors",createCampaign.get("errors"));
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to console log DS.Errors but I'm having trouble outputting the message on the front end. I have {{#each message in errors.messages}}{{message}}{{/each}} but nothing is appearing.

Comment: @Jetchy edited to achieve what you want... but im not sure this is the proper way to do things. I would set the model of the controller to a new empty record instead of creating two property and then create an empty record in the save method. Would make things slightly simpler and more logical.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question on Ember Data Error handling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27736404/2238268) which covers a number of aspects to error handling related to your question.

You don't need to override the ajaxError handling on the adapter any more since my PR was merged into Ember Data.  Errors will be applied to the model correctly now so you can refer to errors using the functions as per my previous answer.